# How to define C-like register macro in C++

Tags: c++, linker-scripts

I always fancy `MODULE_INIT` macro in linux kernel source code. So I try to make similar macro in C++.

AFAIK, `MODULE_INIT` will put a function into a memory section.

So I try,

```
void __attribute__((section("mysec")) func();
```

This works fine when compile with `-o`. But when I link it with `gold` the section disappears in final execution file.

Here is the linker script

```
SECTIONS {
   mysec: {
    __start_mysec = .;
    (*mysec)
    __end_mysec = . ;
  }
}
```

`INSERT AFTER/BEFORE` not work with `gold`, so I ignore it.

So, How do I replicate `MODULE_INIT` macro with c++?

I'm using arm-oe-linux-gnueabi-g++ for this. So `#pragma section` does not exist.

Comment: I suppose just using a static constructor would be too easy?

Comment: @NateEldredge And it take extra time to actual register a module to the system. it would be fine with small system, but it limit the expansion speed of it.

Comment: `[[gnu::section("mysec")]] void func() {}` - new style attribute declaration in front of function appears to work somewhat better.